# I am getting an error when adding an entry to an array

Tags: android, boolean

I intermittently get an error when adding an entry to an array. Any help would be appreciated. My code is:

```
protected ArrayList<String> getSpeedDatesList(){
    int idx = getCurrentIndex();
    speedDatesList = null;
    speedDatesList = new ArrayList<String>(width);
    for(int i=0; i<width - 1; i++) {
        if((speedDatesList != null) && (getSpeedDatesItem(idx) != null)) {
            speedDatesList.add(getSpeedDatesItem(idx));
        }
        idx++;
        if(idx >= (width - 1)){
           idx = 0;
        }
    }

    return speedDatesList;
}
```

And the full error is:

```
03-09 16:26:53.864 3665-5195/uk.co.code2u.cloc_pro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23
Process: `uk.co.code2u.cloc_pro, PID: 3665`
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference 
at uk.co.code2u.cloc_pro.CUserStatistics.getSpeedDatesList(CUserStatistics.java:191)
at uk.co.code2u.cloc_pro.MainStatisticsActivity$MySurfaceView.run(MainStatisticsActivity.java:260)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Could you post the code of `getSpeedDatesItem()`? Perhaps it's `null`ing `speedDatesList`

Comment: `Thread.run()` in the stacktrace suggests you have a race condition.

Comment: private String getSpeedDatesItem(int idx){
        String result = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(theContext).getString(userName + "_stats_speed_time_" + idx, " ");

        return result;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Change to -

```
protected ArrayList<String> getSpeedDatesList(){
    int idx = getCurrentIndex();
    speedDatesList = null;
    speedDatesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++) {
        if((speedDatesList != null) && (getSpeedDatesItem(idx) != null)) {
            speedDatesList.add(getSpeedDatesItem(idx));
        }
        idx++;
        if(idx >= (width - 1)){
           idx = 0;
        }
    }

    return speedDatesList;
}
```

Comment: I originally had this in the code (speedDatesList = new ArrayList<String>();) and I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the array to null and then creating a new ArrayList? From what I can see, speedDatesList is already declared and initialized out of the scope of this function. You can call speedDatesList.Clear() to remove all the items in the list and then add the new items to the previously declared list.

I believe the problem lies with this line of code:

```
speedDatesList = null;
```

and removing it should solve the exception. Just make sure you create an empty list in your onCreate/onStart method.

Comment: setting speedDatesList = null forces the garbage collector to destroy any previous assignments making it ready for a new initialization.

Comment: Sure, but why reinitialize it, when you can use the previous instance and just add the new items? I am not sure if it will work, but you can give it a try, except if you have a specific reason for a new initialization.

Comment: the array must be initialized as it sorts data from a circular buffer into this array ready to be displayed on a graph. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I understand. Sorry my idea could not help. Good luck with finding a solution for the problem!

Comment: Thanks, Man. Your input was very much appreciated.